# Faking a git repository for testing

Tags: ruby, git, testing, rspec

I am writing an application that wraps `git` calls. I need to be able to test it (using `rspec`), so I'm archiving a git repository and extracting it upon test execution.

However, this is becoming tedious because making a change to the test repository means repackaging everything. Also, I need to be able to remember exactly what is contained in the git repository, which makes it hard to use the test repository for multiple test files.

I am looking for something like [fakefs](https://github.com/defunkt/fakefs) where maybe I could do something like the following:

```
before :all do
  @test_repo = FakeGit::init
  @test_repo.add(file)
  @test_repo.commit(file, "Some message") ===> returns "SHA_ID"
end
```

Then somewhere in my test code, I could do something like:

```
it "should point to a SHA_ID" do
  @test_repo.rev_parse("HEAD").should == "SHA_ID"
end
```

Comment: Assuming you really do need to do this, wouldn't the simplest approach be to simply store a script which creates a test repo, rather than the test repo itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does your application do anything beyond wrapping git calls? Does it employ any logic beyond invoking git that need to be tested? If it's simply a wrapper, then testing your application will amount to testing git itself, which is probably redundant.

But if your application brings to the table things beyond simple git calls, you're better off creating a "git call" **interface** (or the closest ruby equivalent) that you **mock** in your tests. You would then be testing your application logic, all the way to when it has to touch actual git calls.

[Look here](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/06/tott-friends-you-can-depend-on.html) for a concise account of the distinction between mocks and fakes. You seem to be trying to create a fake, or even use the real thing. I would recommend looking into mocking rather than **faking/stubbing**.